# How to initialize an object that declared as const on header file?

Tags: c++, file, initialization, ifstream

I want to initialize std::ifstream object only in the `main()` function after declare it in the header.

Is there any way to do it in C++?

I wrote this but it's not compiling

```
//header.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class class1{
        static const std::ifstream fs;
};

//proj.cpp
#include "header.h"

void main(){
        class1::fs("Employee.txt")
}
```

Comment: 1. No, `const` means that is can't be changed outside of the class.    2. `fs` is a `static` variable so it should be initialized outside of the class in a `cpp` file (if you insist you can do it in `proj.cpp`) but **in the global scope**.

Comment: I understand it, but can I **initialize** const object inside of other scope?@רועיאבידן

Comment: No, but in your case I believe instead of initializing it, you can call `fs.open` in main to get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static` variables need to be defined at global scope, not inside a function.

`main` should also return `int` not `void`.

A `const` `std::ifstream` doesn't make much sense as most of the methods you would need to use are non-`const` so wouldn't be callable on your `const` stream.

Fixing these issues gives:

```
//header.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class class1{
        static std::ifstream fs;
};

//proj.cpp
std::ifstream class1::fs("Employee.txt");
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to open the stream in `main` then you need to do:

```
const std::ifstream class1::fs;
int main(){
    class1::fs.open("Employee.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any practical use for a `const ifstream`?

Comment: I wanted to define it as const because, once it's declared, it doesn't need to change its path.

Comment: @PaulSanders good point, probably not, all the useful members are non-const

Comment: @tamir1020 `ifstream` has other state, which it needs to keep up to date as you read the file, so I don't think that's going to work.